# where to put phantomjs.exe in Tomcat 7 on Windows 7

Tags: java, tomcat, highcharts

I want to configure Highstock export server in Tomcat 7.0.55. I followed steps given [here.](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)

**I did not get on this step--> "install PhantomJS on the server, see here"**
I downloaded PhontomJs zip file, extracted to D:\user\softwares\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.

Web app path:D:\user\softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.55-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\webapps

I have given phontomjs.exe file in app-convert.properties
location of the phantomjs executable,

-->exec = D:/user/softwares/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.

**Getting this error:**

```
[ERROR] [pool-1-thread-1 08:13:12] (TaskUtils.java:handleError:95) Unexpected er
ror occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phantomjs":
 CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at com.highcharts.export.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:80)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.ServerObjectFactory.create(ServerObjectFac
tory.java:47)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.ServerObjectFactory.create(ServerObjectFac
tory.java:25)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.AbstractPool.createObject(AbstractPool.jav
a:39)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.AbstractPool.poolCleaner(AbstractPool.java
:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(Sc
heduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnabl
e.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java
:351)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phantomjs": CreateProcess er
ror=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        at com.highcharts.export.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:53)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:188)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
        ... 19 more
```

**where to put phontomjs.exe file into tomcat?**

Comment: It's clear that the path is wrong, have you tried to move phantom.js folder somewhere else, change path and run again?

Comment: @PawelFus, I tried so many ways, but not succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

You need the full path including the exe:

```
exec = D:/user/softwares/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows/phantomjs.exe
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, Still am getting same error on server console.

Comment: Since it's windows, shouldn't be there `\  ` instead of `/ ` ?

Comment: @PawełFus, with Java (and a lot of other programming languages) since `\ ` means escape, you use a `/` for filepaths.  Of course, your suggestion is still worth a shot.

Comment: @Prasad, in addition to what PawelFus says above, you could also try putting `D:\user\softwares\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows` in path.  Then `exec = phantomjs.exe`

Comment: @Mark, thanks, If i put D:\user\softwares\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows in path(windows env variable), the error is resolved but getting "Failed rendering: 
SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string" on the browser, there is no error on server console. when i export JPEG,PNG, it redirects to "http://127.0.0.1:7777/highcharts-export"

Comment: I tried exec = phantomjs.exe and exec = phantomjs, getting Failed rendering: SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string" on the browser.No error on server console.

Comment: That means you have JSON which is invalid.

Comment: @PawelFus,I put phontom.exe file in tomcat bin folder,No error on server console. When i export graph to PNG/JPEG, it will send SVG to server. I tested generated SVG in [Here](http://export.highcharts.com/demo). It will not Append chart data to SVG. Here is [Js code](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6zv/8/)

Comment: Hi, it looks like you're sending directly to the individual phantomjs processes. Instead you should point exporting.url to your Tomcat webapp.